# Emgu CV blob detection in gray image

Tags: emgucv

I am a newbie in image processing. Could anyone teach me how to do blob detection in gray image? A sample code would be really appreciated. I would then have to count the number of blobs present. By the way the input would be from web camera. And also how to determine the size of the blob? Like to compare if the size is almost the same size as a head? Actually I'm doing a head counter where I have to count the number of people passing through the door.

Comment: sample code? this is an extremely complex topic, you won't get code samples I guess. see this: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib

Comment: maybe you could help me with determining the blob size using emgucv

Answer (score 0):

In my comment's linked example:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib

you easily get a `CBlob` object:

```cpp
CBlobResult blobs;
int i;
CBlob *currentBlob;
IplImage *original, *originalThr;

// load an image and threshold it
original = cvLoadImage("pic1.png", 0);
cvThreshold( original, originalThr, 100, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );

// find non-white blobs in thresholded image
blobs = CBlobResult( originalThr, NULL, 255 );
// exclude the ones smaller than param2 value
blobs.Filter( blobs, B_EXCLUDE, CBlobGetArea(), B_LESS, param2 );

// get mean gray color of biggest blob
CBlob biggestBlob;
CBlobGetMean getMeanColor( original );
double meanGray;

blobs.GetNth( CBlobGetArea(), 0, biggestBlob );
meanGray = getMeanColor( biggestBlob );

// display filtered blobs
cvMerge( originalThr, originalThr, originalThr, NULL, displayedImage );

for (i = 0; i < blobs.GetNumBlobs(); i++ )
{
        currentBlob = blobs.GetBlob(i);
        currentBlob->FillBlob( displayedImage, CV_RGB(255,0,0));
}
```

then you can call `Area` or `Perimeter` on it depending on what you need.

Comment: I am working with EmguCV. Could I invoke the cvbloblib in EmguCV??